# How do I add li text to an element on hover jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create something similar to the expertise section of this site: http://www.theelixirhaus.com/

Basically I just want specific text to appear above the icons inside an `<h2>` when you hover over them. Each icon hover brings up different text to the same spot. I attached a JSBin with what I have so far. I'm not sure if a `<p>` within the li is the right thing to use, and how to grab that and display it in the h2.

https://jsbin.com/cefuboxoje/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to this question.  External links are OK but if the link disappears the question becomes incomplete (and impossible to answer)

Comment: Like a [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)?

Answer (score 1):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/388/

if you want to keep your original use of the hover, use `.hover()` instead of `.on('hover', function() {})`

also, you want to use `$(this).find('skills-title').html()` to get the value text inside the `<p>` tag.

i used `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` functions so that when you werent hovering the element, the `<h4>` text would be cleared.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".skills").on('mouseenter',function (){
        var title = $(this).find('.skills-title').html();
        $(".title-shown").html(title);
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(".title-shown").html('');
    });
});
```

ps. you had an extra `class="skills"` in your original jsbin demo in the first `<li>`. not that it would change anything in this case, just friendly reminder to check your code.

Comment: Thanks, that works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `'mouseover'` and `.children().text()` to get to your text:

```
$(".skills").on("mouseover", function (){
  var title = $(this).children().text();
  $(".title-shown").html(title);
});
```

[Here is the demo!](https://jsbin.com/cefuboxoje/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Here's simplified working example of this behavior:

```js
var $h4 = $('h4');

$('ul').on('mouseover', 'a', function(){
  
  var title = $(this).data('title');
  $h4.stop().fadeIn('fast').text( ': '+ title );
  
}).on('mouseout', function(){

  $h4.stop().fadeOut('fast');
  
});
```

```css
h3, h4 { display: inline; }

ul li, ul li a { display:inline-block; }

ul li a {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity .3s;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

ul li a:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
  
  <h3>Expertise</h3>
  <h4></h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" data-title="User-centric empowering">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="Leading scale deliverables">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="World-class expedite vortals">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="Bleeding-edge whiteboard synergies">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
```